# How to get elapsed time from chronometer in android notification

Tags: android

I am displaying a chronometer in my notification:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL)
    ...
    .setUsesChronometer(true)
    .setOngoing(true);

NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
notificationManager.notify(notificationId, builder.build());
```

I would like to get the elapsed time or even the text of the chronometer when the user clicks on that notification.

Comment: The notification API is a write-only API. AFAIK, there is no means to get those details. On the other hand, you know when you displayed the notification, so you can calculate the elapsed time.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for the recommendation. I'll add the same timestamp to my pending intent and then just subtract it from the current timestamp when is handled. Thanks again!